# What is the operator that, for a given basis, creates a vector from an expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider some operator $\mathscr{B}$ such that for a vector space with basis vector $\mathbf{b}$ $$\mathscr{B}\mathbf{b}^{T}=\mathbf{I} $$ or, put another way, if $\mathbf{B}=\textrm{diag }{\mathbf{b}}$, then $$\mathbf{B}^{-1} = \textrm{diag } \mathscr{B} .$$

For example, if we consider the vector space that defines all complex number having the basis vector 
$
\mathbf{b}=
\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 \\ i \end{matrix} \right]
$ then 
$$
\mathscr{B}=
\left[
\begin{matrix}    
\Re \\ \Im
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
since
$$\mathscr{B}\mathbf{b}^{T}=
\left[
\begin{matrix}    
\Re\left\{1\right\} & \Re\left\{i\right\} \\ 
\Im\left\{1\right\} & \Im\left\{i\right\}
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}    
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
=\mathbf{I} . $$
Note that for any complex expression $z = a + ib$, 
$$
\mathscr{B}z = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}    
\Re \\ \Im
\end{matrix}
\right]z
= \left[
\begin{matrix}    
\Re\left\{z\right\} \\ \Im\left\{z\right\}
\end{matrix}
\right]
= \left[
\begin{matrix}    
a \\ b
\end{matrix}
\right] .
$$

**What is the mathematical/linear algebra name for $\mathscr{B}$, if such a term exists?**

*I hope this question has not already been asked, I tried searching but had no idea how to word the whole query.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about the **dual basis** in a vector space. Given a basis $\mathbf{b} = \{e_1,\cdots, e_n\}$ the [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis) is a sequence of linear functionals $\mathbf{b^*}=\{e^1,\cdots, e^n\}$ such that for every vector $x$, $e^k(x)$ is the $k$-th component of the vector $x$ in the basis $\mathbf{b}$. Your operator $\mathscr{B}$ would be the mapping
$$
x\longmapsto (e^1(x),\cdots,e^n(x))
$$
from the vector space $X$ to $\mathbb{K}^n$.

For example if $X=\mathbb{C}$ is the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of complex numbers, equipped with the basis $\mathbf{b} =\{1, i\}$, then the dual basis is $\mathbf{b^*} = \{\Re, \Im\}$. The operator $\mathscr{B}: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ would be
$$\mathscr{B}: z \longmapsto (\Re(z), \Im(z))$$